# auto generate row_key in hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, sqoop, bigdata

I have a log file with records similar to this

```
11,xxx ,dav,300000,mumbai
12,YYY ,IIT,800000,bang
```

When I import it  to hbase using import tsv  ie~

```
ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=,
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,id,name,school,sal,place" 
table_name <file_loc>
```

results:

```
hbase> scan table_name
11                        column=cf:id, timestamp=1501438942080, value=xxx
11                        column=cf:name, timestamp=1501438942080, value=dav
11                        column=cf:sal, timestamp=1501438942080, value=mumbai
11                        column=cf:school, timestamp=1501438942080,value=300000  
12                        column=cf:id, timestamp=1501438942080, value= yyy
12                        column=cf:name, timestamp=1501438942080, value=IIT
```

As the value id is now ROW for HBASE,column:id assinged wrong value xxx.. and so on the next columns,how can I (auto generate a HBASE_ROW_KEY) so that my columns are not overriden? How do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no provision to create composite row keys based on the column values. May be you have pre-process your TSV file and create the composite key and then load it to HBase by using the newly created composite key as your rowKey.

Check the JIRA raised for the same https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HBASE-5339

Comment: preprocessing every tsv file before loading in hbase ....?? Any other solution to create auto generated row in hbase so that importing data to table from external  file would directly load to its respective columns ..

Answer (score 0):

I dont need to add the ( column -> ID ) during  hbase table creation, only the columns which should not be declared PRIMARY_KEY should be given in shell to create table.
Now import tsv will import columns with particular value in each ROW_KEY.